# Tree Implementation in Java

Tags: java, tree

We are implementing a Tree structure and came up with two possible Tree Implementations. Implementation-1 is a straight forward class while Implmentation-2 uses a nested Static Class.

> My Question to reviewers is what are the advantages/disadvantages of 
>   each of the methods below and what is the preferable way ?

**Tree Implementation -1**

```
 public class TreeNode<T> implements Serializable, Iterable<TreeNode<T>> {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      private T name;
      private TreeNode<T> parent;
      private List<TreeNode<T>> children;



    public TreeNode(T data) {
        this.name = data;
        this.children = new ArrayList<TreeNode<T>>();
    }

    public TreeNode<T> addChild(T child) {
        TreeNode<T> childNode = new TreeNode<T>(child);
        childNode.parent = this;
        this.children.add(childNode);
        return childNode;
    }

 }
```

**Tree Implementation-2: Here, we use a Static Nested Class**

```
 public class Node {

    public static class TreeNode1<T>  implements Serializable {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            private String name;
            private TreeNode1<T> parent;
            private List<TreeNode1<T>> children;

            public TreeNode1(String name) {
                this.name = name;
            }

            public void addChild(TreeNode1<T> node) {
                if (children == null)
                    children = new ArrayList<TreeNode1<T>>();
                children.add(node);
                 node.parent = this;
            }


          }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reason for the added complexity of the second implementation. The `Node` class doesn't provide any methods or fields nor does it serve as a base class for your `TreeNode1`. It just makes naming the tree nodes worse: `TreeNode` is definitely a better name than `Node.TreeNode1`.

So in version 2 you end up with two classes:

- The outer class `Node` does nothing useful.
- The node class `Node.TreeNode1` doesn't do anything a non-nested class couldn't do as well.

Even if you embed the `TreeNode1` class into a more functional outer class, there isn't much benefit from static nesting.

So I'd definitely prefer implementation 1.

A nested class can be a good solution in cases where access to the enclosing class is useful, but I'd hide it from the API user, e.g. by exposing a `Node` interface which is internally implemented by the nested class.